# Why Curvature Tensor in Bianchi identity is not all zero

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I am reading Tensor Calculus and Differential Geometry. In chapter4 [ Riemannian Geometry ] under differentail property of Covariant curvature tensor in property 4.1.7.

Where Riemann Christoffel Tensor is given as
[image]

Now, It is mentioned that When any Pole P is choosen then Christoffel Symbols vanish in that pole [ from property of  Christoffel Symbols ]  as below

[image]

which is true but then it is

and Result will be
[image]

Now I was wondering why the first and second term also not zero as these also have Christoffel Symbols term
[image]
 Then second derivatives multiplied by this term should result zero and total sum must be zero.why is not like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a pole?

Comment: They are the derivatives of Christoffel symbol(s), not the Christoffel symbols themselves.  While you can demand $\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}(p)=0$ just by linear change of coordinates, you have no such control over $\partial_k\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}$ or $\partial_m\partial_k\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}$.

Comment: What does $[ki,\,j]$ denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is why a choice that ensures the Christoffel symbols vanish locally doesn't have the same effect on their second derivatives. It comes down to behaviour in a neighbourhood. To take a much simpler example, $x^3-x^2$ vanishes at $x=0$, as does its first derivative $3x^2-2x$, but the second derivative, $6x-2$, doesn't.

Comment: Thanks now i get it.